# Pasar variable de session a una pagina html

Tags: php, html

tenga la pagina login.php

```
session_start();

$user = isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : NULL;
$pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : NULL;

if ($user === "s" && $pass === "s") { //Secretaria
  $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    $_SESSION["area"] = "Secretaria";
    echo $_SESSION["area"];
    header("Location: home-admin.php");
}

elseif($user === "a" && $pass === "a") { //Administración y Finanzas
  $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
  $_SESSION["area"] = "Administración y Finanzas";
  header("Location: home.php");
}
```

necesito pasar la variable area a la pagina week-day.html para despues comparar con el title y si el title es igual a la variable area que me muestre el editar y eliminar, pero no encuentro la forma.

pagina week-day.html

```
<% _.each(events, function(event) { %>
<div class="cal-row-fluid">
    <div class="cal-cell<%= event.days %> cal-offset<%= event.start_day %> day-highlight dh-<%= event['class'] %>"
         data-event-class="<%= event['class'] %>">

        <a href="<%= event.url ? event.url : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>"
           class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>"><span class="badge bg-warning text-dark"><%= event.title %></span></a><br>
<div>
                    

<% if (event.title === 'area') { %>

  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <a href="<%= event.url2 ? event.url2 : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>">
    <span class="editar">Editar</span>
  </a>

  <a href='procesar_eliminar_evento.php?id=<%= event.id %>' alt="ELIMINAR REUNION" title="ELIMINAR REUNION">
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle" onClick="return confirmar()"></i>
    <span class="eliminar" onClick="return confirmar()">Eliminar</span>
  </a>

<% } else{ %>
  <!-- Ocultar editar para otros títulos -->
  <div class="ocultar">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <a href="<%= event.url2 ? event.url2 : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>">
      <span class="editar">Editar</span>
    </a>
    
    <div>    
      <a href='procesar_eliminar_evento.php?id=<%= event.id %>' alt="ELIMINAR REUNION" title="ELIMINAR REUNION">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" onClick="return confirmar()"></i>
        <span class="eliminar" onClick="return confirmar()">Eliminar</span>
      </a>      
    </div>
  </div>

<% } %>
```

Si alguien ya lo hizo y me puede dar una mano, les agradezco a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar una copia del archivo week-day.html pero con el nombre week-day.php y redirecionas a esa pagina, le agregas las variables:

```
<?php $SESSION["Variable"] ?>
```

ya que para datos de session del lenguaje no se puede enviar directamente a menos que los envie por url, cache o localstorage.

Comment: Ya lo hice y no funciona, es mas, las pase todas a php y no funciono, en el script de FullCalendar, llamaba la extension .html tambien las cambie y nada, por lo que veo es problema del css que genera el script, proque esta tomando una fila por registro. Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Los datos de sesión no se 'pasan' a otras páginas sino que -como su nombre lo dice- existen mientras la sesión actual está activa. Para tener acceso a ellas en cualquier página, la **primera** instrucción debe ser

```
session_start();
```

De esa manera se crea una nueva sesión o se continúa una sesión ya existente. De nuevo, es importante que esa sea la primera instrucción que aparezca en tu archivo, de otra manera dará el error "`headers already sent by`".

Comment: Buen dia, ya lo hice, cuando emoiezo la session con session_start(); el caledario no se muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por responder, ya encontre la solucion, tube que agregaar al jquery que obtine los dafos para muestar ahi agregue la variable de sesion y me tomo.

Les comparto lo que hize y que me funciona.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user"]) || (!empty($_SESSION["usuario"]) && $_SESSION["user"] !== 'admin' && $_SESSION["usuario"] !== 'usuario')) {
    $_SESSION["area"];
    header("Location: entrar.html");
  exit();
}

include 'config.php'; 

$area = $_SESSION["area"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM agenda"; 

if ($conexion->query($sql)->num_rows)
{ 
    $datos = array(); 
    $i=0; 
    $e = $conexion->query($sql); 

    while($row=$e->fetch_array()) 
    {
        $row["session_value"] = $_SESSION["area"];
        
        // Fecha inicio
        $Datein                 = date('H:i', strtotime($row['inicio_normal']));
        $inicio=$Datein;
        $row["inicio"] = $inicio;
        
        // Fecha Termino
        $Datefi                    = date('H:i', strtotime($row['final_normal']));
        $final=$Datefi;
        $row["final"] = $final;
        
        $datos[$i] = $row; 
        $i++;
    }
   

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "success" => 1,
            "result" => $datos
        )
    );
}
```